# Encapsulation and data security

Tags: c#, oop, encapsulation

I am trying to understand Object oriented programming. With respect to Encapsulation, I understood it like this.

"Encapsulation, refers to an object's ability to hide data and behavior that are not necessary to other classes& assemblies.

With the help of encapsulation, a class can change the internal implementation without hurting the overall functionality of the system.

**Prevents code (data) from accidental corruption due to programming errors**

Encapsulation enables a group of properties, methods and other members to be considered a single unit or object."

So, when it comes to data hiding/security with encapsulation, I understand it like securing the data from other programmers in the team as there are chances that the data can be corrupted due to programming errors

**My question here is, "Is my understanding about data security/data hiding with respect to encapsulation is correct? Or, whether it is not limited to securing data from programmers alone and it enables securing data from hackers as well ?"**

Comment: Sounds like you need to do more research and become and expert in this to be able to satisfactorily answer it your self. This question is too broad, it asks for off-site resources, as well as opinionated answers. please read the help on asking a question and edit it accordingly so people could potentially help you

Comment: you know whats funny is? - there is WIKI for it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the response. I have edited my question as per your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The encapsulation has nothing to do with outside hackers, it's not a data security concept, it's more about programming model. Here is an example:

```
    class Engine
    {
        public bool Running { get; private set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            this.Running = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            this.Running = false;
        }
    }
```

It's a simple model, `Engine` can `Start`/`Stop` by its instance methods, which essentially changes the `Running` property. If you want to start/stop an `Engine`, just invoke the corresponding method. We can say the behaviors of `Engine` is well encapsulated.

Let's change the code

```
    class Engine
    {
        public bool Running { get; set; }    //set is changed to public
    }
```

Now the code is shorter and simpler, if we want to start an engine just set `Running` to `true` (or false when you want to stop). As the project grows, you will have several methods that will change `Running` property to start an engine.

Here comes a new case1: sometimes the engine is out-of-control then it can't be started/stopped. If you are using the old version, it's easy to change the code to:

```
    class Engine
    {
        public bool Running { get; private set; }

        public bool OutOfControl { get; private set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (this.OutOfControl) return;
            this.Running = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (this.OutOfControl) return;
            this.Running = false;
        }

        public void SomeOperation()
        {
            //inside the method sometimes OutOfControl is set to true
        }
    }
```

The callers of `Engine.Start` and `Engine.Stop` will not be affected. What about the "simpler" version? You need to change 10+(or 100+) callers, checking `OutOfControl` property before changing `Running` property.

And then here comes a new case2, case3...the "simpler" version is becoming harder and harder to maintain. Because it exposes the implementation details to callers. Every time the start/stop implementation changes, the first version (well-encapsulated version) only needs to change the start/stop method, because it's the only place that performs the behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Danny Chen. This is what I was looking for. Some of the blogs I have gone through created this confusion in me that encapsulation is for data security as well. So, wanted to clarify that. Your answer helped me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is more of logic perspective on writing code rather than people perspective. Encapsulation is the act of hiding the details which are not relevant.

For example, you use a Computer. But you don't see what CPU looks like. Its sort of encapsulated or hidden behind all plastic stuff.

In Object oriented programming, one usually have this kind of code:

```
CLASS {
  METHOD { 
    // some code
  }
}
```

An example of "encapsulation" would be having a METHOD that the regular user can't see (example: private).

**Encapsulation:**- Information hiding.

Real life examples of encapsulation:

1. Capsule
2. Wallet
3. Box